# Replace individual parts of Supabase, is it possible and supported?

Tags: supabase

I'd like to understand if Supabase allows to replace the individual services that compose it, for example, if I ever need to replace GoTrue with another auth service, would that be possible? And is this something they support?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be possible! All the data you have for your Supabase instance is stored in the database, so you can always export the data and migrate to something else.